# How to check if a particular service is running in a remote computer using PowerShell

Tags: powershell

I have 3 servers, running 3 services:

- SERVER-A running `serv1.exe`  service
- SERVER-B running `serv2.exe`  service
- SERVER-C running `serv3.exe`  service

Using PowerShell how can I query each service to check if they are running and output the information to a text file?

Answer (score 14):

If they all have the same name or display name you can do it in one command. If not you need to run  3 commands.

If all have the same name or display name:

```
Get-Service -ComputerName server-a, server-b, server-c -Name MyService | 
  Select Name, MachineName, Status
```

If they have different names or display names:

I would do this --

```
@{
  'server-a' = 'service-a'
  'server-b' = 'service-b'
  'server-c' = 'service-c'
}.GetEnumerator() | ForEach-Object {
  Get-Service -ComputerName $_.Name -Name $_.Value
} | Select Name, MachineName, Status
```

To output to a text file use `... | Set-Content ~\Documents\Service_Status.txt` where `...` is one of the above.

Note - your account will need to have privileges to query the remote machines.

Comment: How do you specify an alternative credential if your account doesn't have permission?

Comment: @Dan, you need to use [Invoke-Command](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/invoke-command?view=powershell-6) in this case.

Comment: If your service name has a special character in it like `$` then you will need to surround the entire name with single quotes like: `get-service -computername ServerName -Name 'Service$Name'

Comment: Does the get-service also supports wild card ?

Answer (score 3):

There are several ways to achieve this. I am using a hash of the values since you mentioned that the server to service mapping is always one to one.

```
$svrHash = @{"SERVER-01"="winmgmt";"SERVER-02"="Wecsvc"}
$svrHash.Keys 
  | ForEach-Object {Get-Process -ComputerName $_ -Name $svrHash[$_] -Ea SilentlyContinue} 
  | Select ProcessName 
  | Out-File C:\Scripts\test.txt
```

You need to use the service name and not the .exe name.

Comment: Thanks it worked. But I was wrong in explaining my requirement.They are Tasks and NOT services. If i open Task Manager, I should be able to see 3 different tasks in 3 different servers.

Comment: So, they are processes and not services? Replace Get-Service with Get-Process and it should work.

Comment: Yes it worked. The log contains too much details like Handles  NPM(K),PM(K),WS(K),VM(M),CPU(s),Id, Process name. Is it possible to have only 2 colums as the output ( Process Name and Running (Yes or No ))  Thanks

Comment: What do you mean by running status? A process will appear in Get-Process output only when it is running. So, if a specific process or server name is not listed in your output file, it just means that the process is not running. I updated my answer.

Comment: Ok, Understood, but I was planning a formatted output. Not necessary. Only prob was, if there are 2 DIFFERENT processes runnung on the same server, the Hash table does no permit assigning 2 values like, $svrHash = @{"SERVER-01"="winmgmt";"SERVER-01"="Wecsvc"}
As far as single process in single server it works. How can it be extended to 2/3 different tasks in same server ?

Comment: , if there are 2 DIFFERENT processes runnung on the same server, the Hash table does no permit assigning 2 values like, $svrHash = @{"SERVER-01"="winmgmt";"SERVER-01"="Wecsvc"} As far as single process in single server it works. How can it be extended to 2/3 different tasks in same server ?