# How to check different services on different servers in powershell scripting?

Tags: powershell, powershell-3.0

```powershell
$c = Get-Content D:\Users\vbaranwa\Desktop\vb.txt
for ($i = 0; $i-le $c.count; $i++) {
  $a = ($c)[$i]
  Get-Service -ComputerName $a -Name Power | select Name, MachineName, Status 
}
```

This is working if the services are same but if there are different services to check then how it can be done?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For the Name parameter, you can specify multiple patterns and wildcards can be used in the patterns. You can use your `get-service` command as flollowing:

```
$c= Get-Content D:\Users\vbaranwa\Desktop\vb.txt
for($i=0; $i-le $c.count; $i++)
{
    $a=($c)[$i]
    get-service -ComputerName $a -Name *pattern1*, *pattern2*, *pattern3* |select Name, MachineName, Status
}
```

You can refer to the following link on how to use the parameter for this command:
[Get-Service Cmdlet](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh849804.aspx)

I did some search and found this [SO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17768989/check-if-a-particular-service-is-running-in-a-remote-computer-using-powershell-s) link should be talking the same problem you encountered:
[How to check if a particular service is running in a remote computer using PowerShell](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17768989/check-if-a-particular-service-is-running-in-a-remote-computer-using-powershell-s)

You can refer to the SO link to configure which server have which service in the code, or you can have a change in your vb.txt file (I assume now this file only contains the server names) to configure which server have which services like:

```
server1, service1
server2, service2
server3, service3
server3, service4
```

And then the code will be changed to:

```
$c= Import-CSV -header server, service D:\Users\vbaranwa\Desktop\vb.txt
for($i=0; $i-le $c.count; $i++)
{
    $server  = $c[$i].server
    $service = $c[$i].service
    get-service -ComputerName $server -Name $service |select Name, MachineName, Status
}
```

Comment: actually i was asking about different services on different servers
eg.  server1  -- service1
     server2  -- service2
how can it be done????